# 403 error with nginx + passenger + rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have simple application which works well on Apache but gives me error 403 after moving to Nginx.

Here is my configuration:

`server {`

```
    server_name  myapp.com;
    access_log  off;
    root /home/www/myapp/public;
    autoindex on;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
```

}

Nginx is running from www-data user which has r+x permissions to all the folders on the path to the application.

Nginx is 0.8.54 and Passenver is 3.0.5.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Obviously no reasonable errors in nginx log file (I increased logging level to maximum) and also nothing in rails log files.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the http port:

```
server {
  listen 80;
   ...
}
```